# Fill in rows missing row labels for repeated values

Tags: awk

I have the following input:

```
printf "Name\tArea\tNumber\tA\tB\tC\n\t\t\tA\tB\tC\n\t\t\tA\tB\tC\n"
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
                        A       B       C
                        A       B       C
```

If first 3 columns are blank, 
I want to print the previous 3 columns along with the data of the new line, 
else print the line as is. Output should look like this:

```
printf "Name\tArea\tNumber\tA\tB\tC\nName\tArea\tNumber\tA\tB\tC\nName\tArea\tNumber\tA\tB\tC\n"
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the question is that fields 1 to 3 can appear anywhere in the file, with values possibly different from the ones they had previously. So the idea would be to reproduce the last fields 1 to 3 seen so far, so that the input:

```
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
                        A       B       D
                        F       G       T
Nam     Zig     BBA     U       Z       x
                        A       B       D
```

would produce the output:

```
Name    Area    Number  A   B   C
Name    Area    Number  A   B   D
Name    Area    Number  F   G   T
Nam Zig BBA U   Z   x
Nam Zig BBA A   B   D
```

So I propose:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"; hd1=hd2=hd3=""} $1=="" {$1=hd1;$2=hd2;$3=hd3; print; next} {hd1=$1;hd2=$2;hd3=$3; print}' yourfile
```

ok, I only checked the non-nullity of $1, but we could easily adapt to add only the missing fields.

Comment: Dear Jaybee, you assumed right, it worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this as a fixed width problem. A GNU awk solution:

```
$ awk '$1~/^ +$/{sub($1,h)}{h=$1}1' FIELDWIDTHS=23 file         
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
Name    Area    Number  A       B       D
Name    Area    Number  F       G       T
Nam     Zig     BBA     U       Z       x
Nam     Zig     BBA     A       B       D
```

Just change the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable to match your data as needed.

The other more verbose approach is to iterate over each of the fields that could be missing:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=c;i++)if($i=="")$i=h[i]}{for(i=1;i<=c;i++)h[i]=$i}1' c=3 FS='\t' OFS='\t' file
Name    Area    Number  A       B       C
Name    Area    Number  A       B       D
Name    Area    Number  F       G       T
Nam     Zig     BBA     U       Z       x    
Nam     Zig     BBA     A       B       D
```

Just change `c` to the value of missing columns you want to check.